# Operator overload for struct

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, sortcomparefunction

I am not able to get this code work. I have read similar questions on the topic but I couldn't find a solution.
error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'car' and 'const int')
       { return *__it < __val; }
That was the only meaningful hint in a lengthy error message.

```
struct car{
string name;
int l,h;
int operator<(/*const car& a,*/const car& b){
    return (this->l)<=(b.l);
};
int main(){int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
int n;
cin>>n;
 vector<struct car> a(n);
int i=0;
while(i<n){
    ws(cin);cin>>a[i].name>>a[i].l>>a[i++].h;
}
sort(a.begin(),a.end());
//more code }
```

Even creating a compare function with two arguements didn't work.
Any helpwill be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Define doesn't work. Won't compile? Fails at runtime? What's the actual problem? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: it doesn't compile and the error message was very big and unreadable

Comment: using bool return type instead of int didn't work either.

Comment: Where is your operator that takes `car` on the left and `const int` on the right? I can't see it, and neither can the compiler!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is lacking the actual question, but two things are obvious:

1) You're violating strict weak ordering - if `a < b` then `b < a` cannot be true. Your comparison function breaks this. In fact, you're implementing `operator<` in terms of `operator<=`, which should be a red flag.

2) your code could use a little formatting. Use clang-format or formatting function of your IDE for this (or a web interface for clang-format: [link](http://format.krzaq.cc/)).

Comment: sorry for formatting..i am a newbie. But where did I break point 1?

Comment: For `Car c; c.l = 0;` and `Car d; d.l = 0;` both `c < d` and `d < c` are true.

Comment: removing equality condition didn't work either.And the code doesn't even compile, still my input data ensures non zero value. But thanks for pointing out

Comment: I can see why: put your code into the linked formatter and see what happens. Each `{` needs a `}` and not in the random place. Points raised by my answer still stand, though. And it's not just for `0`, it's for any equal values - `sort` and standard algorithms using `operator<` determine object equality by checking `a<b` and `b<a` and both returning false

Comment: is my struct declaration and overloading fine?

Comment: It's mostly fine, for a newbie. [here](https://gist.github.com/KrzaQ/8455956b40b58a074105167bd87acbed)'s a version that should compile.

Comment: Thank You Sir. What was the issue?

Comment: Missing `}`s, incorrect `operator<` semantics and, as @iMADik pointed out, incorrect return type of that operator (that was harmless in this case, though).